# SSMS shortcut to navigate between open query windows

Tags: sql-server, ssms, keyboard-shortcuts

I sometimes have a large amount of query windows open in SSMS 2008.

Is there a keyboard shortcut to navigate between open query windows? Go to previous/next open query window?

I know there is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> that allows you to select a query window, but it's only helpful if you have named windows.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

A challenge you'll find here is what does "next" really mean? Since you can tear off tabs, split the UI, even move tabs onto different monitors, I think "next" and "previous" lose a little meaning, unless you know what order they were opened in.

Anyway, some solutions, with older versions (based on when the question was asked) left intact:

**SSMS 2008**

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> will switch between two most recent tabs. And honestly, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> work like next/previous except you have to hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> twice (you can ignore knowing what the name of the tab in the list is).

**SSMS 2012**

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> will cycle through open tabs in the order they are displayed, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> will cycle in the reverse direction.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> will open a temporary window and allow you to cycle through open queries in the order they were last opened.

**In more recent decades**

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+[<kbd>Page Up</kbd>|<kbd>Page Down</kbd>] will cycle through windows (as [bridge_burner added](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56960055/61305)), but there's a catch. This only works when the query window is active - and it will stop working if you get to a query window where, previously, you had an item in the grid selected, for example.
- You can make your own keyboard shortcut, as [Stuart Smith explains](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73154238/61305).

Comment: Thanks! Guess it is the Ctrl+F6 I was looking for as I just want to quickly cycle through the open windows. Ctrl+Tab opens that intermediate window which makes it slow... Will see if I can upgrade to 2012.

Comment: just to be clear - Ctrl + F6 iterates circularly through the open tabs

Comment: Don't hit CTRL+F5 by mistake though as this will execute your script. I don't like this as a shortcut to cycle through tabs/windows.

Comment: @AndyRobertson: In the current version (SSMS 18.x), the `CTRL+F5` no longer executes the script, it only Parses the script.  The default key to execute it is `CTRL+E`

Answer (score 18):

the equivalent of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> in browsers for SSMS would be <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PageDown</kbd> for next tab and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PageUp</kbd> for previous tab.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Ctrl+Alt+PageDown / Up are, actually, faster to reach and much more mnemonic than the other methods suggested, which require multiple steps and prior visual evaluation.

Comment: **Note**, Ctrl + Alt + PageDown / Up just go through the **visible** tabs and, oddly enough, this shortcut is not listed in the official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/sql-server-management-studio-keyboard-shortcuts?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 6):

Here's my approach that get's me closer to coding utopia. Make sure you keep your SSMS query windows sorted by name from left to right. SQLQuery1.sql, SQLQuery2.sql, etc. These are the default names SSMS gives these tabs when you create them (by clicking New Query).

To change the current query window tab, press "alt" then "w" then "w". A window is shown listing all of your open query windows sorted by their names (which should be the same order in which you have them laid-out from left to right). Use the up and down arrow keys to highlight the tab you want to activate and press enter. Your desired tab should be open now.

This allows me to quickly change query windows while keeping my fingers on the keyboard (less mouse usage).

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a *very* old thread, but I thought I would add one more suggestion in case someone else comes across this: Redgate's SQL Prompt comes with a nifty "Tab History" applet that gets added as a button to a toolbar. I know that that means you would have to leave the keyboard and reach for the mouse to access it, but the interface and its functionalities are worth it! Not only do you have access to the currently opened tabs (with visual mini previews of the code in each tab) but also you have access to recently **closed** tabs (Yes, it may save you in case you accidentally close a tab without saving your work...)

Just my two cents. Best, Raphael

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+X will open SQL Prompt's tab history and Ctrl+Arrow will move between All, Open, Close, and Starred.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to map the browser style next/previous tab shortcuts in SSMS.

Select **Tools** > **Options**. Under 'Environment' select '**Keyboard**'. In the 'Show commands containing:' area type '**Window.**'.

Find '**Window.NextTab**'. Toggle the 'Use new shortcut in:' to '**SQL Query Editor**' then enter <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>PgDn</kbd> in the 'Press shortcut keys:' area and select 'Assign'. Do the same steps for '**Window.PreviousTab**' with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>PgUp</kbd>.

[SSMS Keyboard Shortcuts Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P10JH.png)